# What is the correct form of won't or are not going to?

Tags: future, synonyms

What is the correct form?

> I hope in the future we won't go to school in the morning
>
> I hope in the future we are not going to go to school in the morning

Answer (score 0):

I understand the first as "I hope in the future that during any morning we will not go to school". It is quite a common construction and well understood. The second is almost the same but has the extra feeling that there is some particular morning in the future when I hope we will not be going to school. The second also feels ponderous and awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Neither form makes much sense, but both are gramatically acceptable.
I think what the sentences are trying to say is something like:
I hope in the future we won't be required to go to school in the morning. or
I hope in the future we won't have to go to school in the morning.